# Chromedriver not working with Alpine base docker image

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux

I have one app, which uses alpine based image, and i have chrome driver in given directory(/usr/bin/chromedriver/linux64/2.45/chromedriver) with 755 permission.

I get below given error :

```
chromedriver-docker-example_1  | 2019-03-20 05:05:50.316 ERROR 21 --- [ null to remote] org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess         : org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/chromedriver/linux64/2.45/chromedriver" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory)
```

Can please anyone help on this ?

Comment: Could you please share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Have you double checked that the file does indeed exist in your container?

Comment: Hello, we are having the exact same issue, did anyone find a solution? we are certain the file is in that directory, same directory as selenium jar, which is being executed like this:

```java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar ${SELENIUM_JAR_FILE} -role node -hub ${SELENIUM_HUB_URL} -browser "browserName=chrome,version=${CHROME_VERSION},platform=LINUX,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver,maxInstances=1"```

```Cannot run program "/selenium/chromedriver" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory```

Alpine: 3.9
Java: 8.191.12
Selenium: 3.141.59
Chromedriver: 2.42

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, if you found a solution can you please share.

Comment: FYI alpine is based on `musl`, not `glibc`, which chromedriver needs to work. Here is an alpine impl of gcc: https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve it, for alpine we need to install chromium driver, chromium. Add below given command to setup it.

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash \
        alsa-lib \
        at-spi2-atk \
        atk \
        cairo \
        cups-libs \
        dbus-libs \
        eudev-libs \
        expat \
        flac \
        gdk-pixbuf \
        glib \
        libgcc \
        libjpeg-turbo \
        libpng \
        libwebp \
        libx11 \
        libxcomposite \
        libxdamage \
        libxext \
        libxfixes \
        tzdata \
        libexif \
        udev \
        xvfb \
        zlib-dev \
        chromium \
        chromium-chromedriver
```

And then point driver path to /usr/bin/chromedriver.
This should solve given issue.

Comment: What's the command for changing the driver path? That is, which environment variable do we need to set?

Comment: ENV PATH="/usr/bin/chromedriver:${PATH}"

Comment: I'm not sure why the answer suggests you need all those packages. I could just add `chromium-chromedriver` and everything worked. Thanks! Also you can use `node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor.conf.js --chromeDriver=/usr/bin/chromedriver` to point to the installed driver if you use protractor directly from the commandline

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you